# Is it possible to make a tall live tile? How?

Tags: tiles, live-tiles

I want to make an TODO list application. It's just something to get me started with windows phone development. A small square or a wide live tile only allows me to show one or two tasks. I want a live tile that is taller than it is wide. This will display documents or lists a lot better than a wide tile. I'm thinking that Microsoft would have to update the OS to provide this capability. Is this possible or is it all driven by the OS?

Also I can't seem to make any suggestions to the Windows phone feature suggestion http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions. Is there an alternative location to suggest something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean making a live tile on the phone start screen, then no, you're limited to the 3 official sizes that WP8 supports.

The feature suggestions URL you have is correct.

Comment: +1 An alternative might be allowing the user to pin a secondary tile. While it doesn't give you a bigger tile it will give you more real estate.